# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, html

I have to search for CVE's or Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures through a search query on a website and then print the import the resulting table in my print request. The website I'm using for scraping of the results are https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=CVE+2017

I'm using python 3 to code and am new to it and wanted to use this as a project

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
searchStr = input("Enter Search Query \n")
r = urllib.request.urlopen("https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?
keyword="+searchStr)
source_code = r.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('tbody', id = 'TableWithRules')
rows = table.find('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.find('td')
    p = cols[0].text.strip()
    d = cols[1].text.strip
    print(p)
    print(d)
```

Gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu Misra\Desktop\Python\CVE_Search.py", line 9, in 
<module>
    rows = table.find('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: `soup.find('tbody', id='TableWithRules')` is returning `None`, so `table = None`, then you are doing `table.find('tr')` and `None.find()`is undefined.

Comment: also you are searching the wrong tag .The id (TableWithRules) is associated to a div tag and you have written tbody

Comment: Also you have to use find_all for getting all rows and all columns .find() will find only the first occurence and therefore will not return a result set

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! But the returned data set is losing its tabular structure which is also to be corrected. I will get on that now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the 'correct'answer is not correct
this line is wrong:

`divtag=soup.find('div',{'id':'TableWithRules'})`

It should be:

`table=soup.find('div',{'id':'TableWithRules'})`

Comment: Well put sir. I'll edit the answer right away. Also, it is the correct answer since it solves the problem, and we can always ignore the silly mistakes. Thanks for the correction tho

Answer (score 5):

```
import urllib.request
searchStr = input("Enter Search Query \n")
r = urllib.request.urlopen("https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?
keyword="+searchStr)
source_code = r.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')

# FIRST OF ALL SEE THAT THE ID "TableWithRules" is associated to the divtag 

table = soup.find('div', {"id" : 'TableWithRules'})
rows=table.find_all("tr")   # here you have to use find_all for finding all rows of table
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.find_all('td') #here also you have to use find_all for finding all columns of current row
    if cols==[]: # This is a sanity check if columns are empty it will jump to next row
        continue
    p = cols[0].text.strip()
    d = cols[1].text.strip()
    print(p)
    print(d)
```